# Automating boot up

Tags: dell-poweredge

So, I have recently acquired a dell r710 for use a both a web server and a file server (Ik shoulda got a nas) and a minor annoyance is it requires user input to continue booting into the hostOS (ESXi) is there any way for me to make it not require me to press F1 every time I reboot?

I case it helps the hostOS is stored on an internal USB with 1 actual drive for the data.

Comment: Why does it want you to press F1 on every boot?  Also, http://www.ebay.com/bhp/drinking-bird-toy

Comment: It would make sense to tell us WHY you have to push F1 every time. Obviously this is not normal behavior.

Comment: @womble it shows up after iDrac informs me of its network connection, it doesn't have any error message just press key to continue or key to enter setup

Comment: That's not normal behavior. It's asking you to press F1 because something in POST isn't occurring normally. If it's doing it while/after initializing the iDRAC that usually means that the iDRAC initialization has failed. If it is a problem with the iDRAC you can try an "i" button reset of the iDRAC, a "flea power drain" reset of the iDRAC, or a jumper reset of the iDRAC.

Comment: A common source of that on Poweredge servers is a drained battery, usually in the disk controller. You may see it complaining in `dmesg` or install the Dell management tools (`omreport` etc) to see where the hardware is reporting issues.

Answer (score 2):

That message is typically caused by hardware issues, but 11G servers will sometimes keep displaying the prompt even after the issue is resolved. You can press F2 to enter system setup and then immediately save and exit - if the hardware status is good, saving the settings will reset the error prompt and it'll boot normally.

If the prompt still comes back after that, you should boot into the lifecycle controller (press F10 during POST) and run hardware diagnostics.

There's also an option at the bottom of the F2 menu to disable the F1 prompt entirely, but that's a band-aid solution and it won't fix the underlying problem.